# Android: How can I get a file path to the matching thumbnail URI?

Tags: android, file, path, thumbnails

I have got an Android grid view gallery that uses thumbnails to show the images and now I want to get the "real" file path of the related image on the SD card.

What I have got is the thumbnail media URI, something like this as URI: content://media/external/images/thumbnails/277 (content URI) or the absolute path of the thumbnail: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1335263816935.jpg

But I want to get the image URI/path of this thumbnail i.e. something like this /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/thisIsTheImageOfTheRelatedThumnailNumber234.jpg.

How is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnail keeps id of image.

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail();
```

You can parse it and then run query to get this image by id from all Images.